# Adding a several random numbers to graphics context above images

Tags: java, random, arraylist, iterator, javafx-2

I am creating a old school game where the user has to collect the falling objects. Currently I have an image that is printed to the `GraphicsContext` several times accross the pane and is added and removed from an `arrayList(`) when it disappears off of the screen. I can create a random number and I can print this to the same position as the falling image. However the random number is always the same and I want the number to be different on each of the objects. My code in my start method is as follows:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<800; i+=90)

arrayList.add(new Object(ImageView, noOnImage, i,-10));
```

I then also have an update method where the objects are continously redrawn:

```
int newObject = 0;
Iterator<Object> objectIterator = object.iterator();
while(objectIterator.hasNext())
{
     Object ob = objectIterator.next();

    if(ob.move())
    {
        objectIterator.remove();
        newObject++;

    }                           
    gc.drawImage(ob.objectImage,ob.r.getX(), ob.r.getY(), ob.r.getWidth(),
        ob.r.getHeight());
    gc.fillText(String.valueOf(noOnImage), ob.r.getX()+8, ob.r.getY()+22);
}
```

`noOneImage` is just a randomly generated number that I declared at the top. I would like each object to contain a different random value, currently they are all the same though, even though it is random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the object, pass in the random number within your loop.

```
Random rand = new Random()
arrayList.add(new Object(ImageView, noOnImage, i,-10, rand.nextInt(0, 10)));
```

That rand will give you a number between 0 and 10. You can put whatever `int` you want in there.

And make sure the `object` you create has the field and you are able to retrieve this number (e.g. for a score tally, etc.).